How can I install Mavericks on an new Mac?
I have a Mac mini m2 and I need to install macOS Mavericks on it. I can't find any patcher or something that could help me.

Do you have a particular project in mind? If we knew more about it, we might be able to suggest a workable solution. As your question stands, the answer can only be "no you can't".

macOS 10.9, aka Mavericks, does not support Apple Silicon devices. macOS 10.9 was released in 2013 and compiled for Intel hardware.
The Mac Mini M2 (2023) shipped with macOS 13.2. It is unlikely any earlier version of macOS will work on the device.
If this is for work or a commercial project, consider purchasing a second hand Intel based Mac Mini, or renting time with a device on AWS or MacStadium.

Thanks! I was already planning to buy a little older mac.

You can't.  macOS (and before that OS X) only "know about" Macs that were available at the time that version was released. Mavericks (OS X 10.9) was released in 2013, long before the M2 Mini.
My advice is to get a used Mac Mini 2012.
The alternative is to use UTM virtual machine software which is able to emulate Intel processors. It is possible that it can be made to run OS X 10.13. If it can be made to do so, OS X 10.13 would be excruciatingly slow. I don't recommend pursuing that path.

I used qemu on windows to run 10.3 but I don't know will it run 10.9
